# Dataframe cummin column that starts at a specific index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of two columns. Date and an decimal number. 
I want to create a new column in the dataframe that displays the cummin of the decimal number column only for when time has past 9:30

[image]

Comment: Can you convert the example to text please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `mask` to mask, followed by `cummin`.

```
# df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, errors='coerce')
df['cummin'] = df.number.mask(df.index.strftime('%H:%M') < '09:30').cummin()
```

You can also query the `hour` and `minute` attribute of the index to get the hours:

```
df['cummin'] = df.loc[
    (df.index.hour >= 9) & (df.index.minute > 30), 'number'].cummin()
```

---

MCVE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1.4, 4.5, 2.3], 
                  index=['9:00', '9:31', '9:45'], 
                  columns=['number'])
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df
                     number
2018-12-21 09:00:00     1.4
2018-12-21 09:31:00     4.5
2018-12-21 09:45:00     2.3
```

```
df.assign(number=(
    df.number.mask(df.index.strftime('%H:%M') < '09:30').cummin()))

                     number  cummin
2018-12-21 09:00:00     NaN     NaN
2018-12-21 09:31:00     4.5     4.5
2018-12-21 09:45:00     2.3     2.3
```

```
df.assign(number=df.loc[
    (df.index.hour >= 9) & (df.index.minute > 30), 'number'].cummin())

                     number  cummin
2018-12-21 09:00:00     NaN     NaN
2018-12-21 09:31:00     4.5     4.5
2018-12-21 09:45:00     2.3     2.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `between_time` with `expanding`

```
df['new']=df.between_time('09:30','23:59').expanding().min()
df
                     number  new
2018-12-20 09:00:00     1.4  NaN
2018-12-20 09:31:00     4.5  4.5
2018-12-20 09:45:00     2.3  2.3
```